# Condição if and else com data no crystal report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Estou realizando uma condição no meu relatório com o objetivo de inserir `"-"` quando a data Vencimento vier nula, porém ocorre erro quando a data vem diferente de nulo. Abaixo está a imagem que mostra o erro quando preencho a data vencimento:

[image: imagem erro relatório]

Foi utilizado a seguinte expressão no relatório report:

```
=IIf(Fields!DataVencimentoPago.Value <> "",Format(Fields!DataVencimentoPago.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy"),"-")
```

Tentei também de outra forma, porém sem sucesso:

```
=IIf(Fields!DataVencimentoPago.Value <> "", Fields!DataVencimentoPago.Value,"-")
```

Answer (score 1):

Identificado o problema o componente utilizado que report não aceita valores nulos no campo, assim foi realizado a seguinte alteração :

=IIf(Fields!DataPagamento.Value <> "01/01/0001 00:00:00",FormatDateTime(Fields!DataPagamento.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate),"-")

problema resolvido com sucesso!